# Data passed to php file does not allow MySQL connection

Tags: php, mysql

So I deleted my last post because I don't think I made my problem concise enough. Basically I want to create a MySql connection in my php file using a variable passed from my main page (JS) My index page passes the variable as follows:

```js
$.ajax({
   url: "php/ajax.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: {name:'3404-11833'},
   success: function(data){
            window.location.assign("http://www.dasite.com/" + myloc + ".html");
       }
   });
}
```

The PHP file is as follows:

```php
<?php

/* Database Configuration.*/

$name = $_POST['name'];
$test = strval('3404-11833');

$dbOptions = array(
'db_host' => '',
'db_user' => '',
'db_pass' => '',
'db_name' => $name
);

/* Database Config End */

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

require "classes/DB.class.php";
require "classes/Chat.class.php";
require "classes/ChatBase.class.php";
require "classes/ChatLine.class.php";
require "classes/ChatUser.class.php";

session_name('webchat');
session_start();

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){

array_walk_recursive($_GET,create_function('&$v,$k','$v = stripslashes($v);'));
array_walk_recursive($_POST,create_function('&$v,$k','$v = stripslashes($v);'));
}

try{

// Connecting to the database
DB::init($dbOptions);

$response = array();

// Handling the supported actions:

switch($_GET['action']){

    case 'login':
        $response = Chat::login($_POST['name']);
    break;

    case 'checkLogged':
        $response = Chat::checkLogged();
    break;

    case 'logout':
        $response = Chat::logout();
    break;

    case 'submitChat':
        $response = Chat::submitChat($_POST['chatText']);
    break;

    case 'getUsers':
        $response = Chat::getUsers();
    break;

    case 'getChats':
        $response = Chat::getChats($_GET['lastID']);
    break;

    default:
        throw new Exception('Wrong action');
}

echo json_encode($response);
}
catch(Exception $e){
die(json_encode(array('error' => $e->getMessage())));
}

?>
```

Now, when I use $test, the code works fine, however when I switch to $name, I get a database error. Is this a formatting issue or am I doing something else wrong?
*Also, YES, I am aware of injection, it is not a problem here.

Comment: You should post your database code and a `var_dump()` of the variables. But user-provided input should never be able to cause a database error.

Comment: There is no user-provided input.  Should I post the full database code here, or should I close this and make a new question?

Comment: I added the full php file. Do you need to see the required class files as well?

Comment: What I wanted to see was the difference between the two strings when you do a `var_dump()` and how you select your table. But looking at the variable names, I had an idea already, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If both strings contain exactly the same value, they either both work, or neither of them works.

Personally I don't use database names that start with numbers, but I would assume that you would need to escape them the same way you escape table- or column names: Using backticks:

```
'db_name' => "`{$name}`";
```

Comment: The $test definitely works, and $name definitely does not work. That is what is confusing me, because as far as I see it should work, but it doesn't, I tried using backticks, that did not work either.

Comment: @user3634006 If one works and the other not, the strings are not the same, check the exact values.

Comment: I will do a var_dump() and see what spits out, but the strings are exactly the same (as far as I can tell) Thank you for your help jeroen, I really appreciate your time.

Comment: ok, when I did a var_dump, I got a NULL string(10) so yes, this is one of the problems, thank you. This then make the question, what I wrong with my ajax? Why does it not send the string from my js to my php file? I don't see anything wrong with my ajax.

Comment: @user3634006 Hard to tell without seeing everything, but you could try quoting your array key: `data: {'name': '3404-11833'},`. The string(10) part seems to be correct, it is the key that is missing. Assuming you dumped `$_POST`...

Comment: Here's an idea: I do not go from my index page directly to the php. I go from the index to a separate html file, which then sends information to a js script file, and that file is the one that uses ajax.php to establish a db connection. I never go from my index directly to my php file. Could this be why the variable is not passing correctly?

Comment: quoting the array key does not fix it.

Comment: @user3634006 Does it work when you comment out your `window.location.assign()` line?

Comment: no, it does not work when I comment that out. I am going to look at this a few other ways, this thread is starting to get long so I want to thank you all for trying to help me, if I cannot crack it in a few days, I may be back to ask assistance, but while not all the way to a solution yet, you have indeed helped me out. Thank You.